# How to get Button1 Id on button2 click on server side asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

here is my aspx view

```
            <asp:GridView ID="gvdatasubcategory" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false"
            CssClass="gvdatarow" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvdatasubcategory_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="subcategory_type">
                            <div id="abd" runat="server">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="button1" runat="server" CssClass="subcategory_name"
                                    Width="80px" Height="26px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubCategory")%>'
                                    CommandName="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" Width="5px" />
                    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Estrangelo Edessa" Width="5px" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="button2 " runat="server" CssClass="category_name" Text="getid"
                                OnClick="button2 _Click" />
```

these buttons are in gridview and i need to get the first button id on second button click in code behind 
Thank you in advance
Raveendra

Comment: Button id? or the text that was binded to it?

Comment: this.button1.ClientID ?

Comment: Can you give some more information about the functionality you are trying to create? I expect that the gridview contains multiple rows and therefore button1 is not directly reachable

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Linkbutton object, thenyou can use `FindControl` method as:

```
LinkButton button1 = (LinkButton)gvdatasubcategory.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("button1");
string buttonid = button1.ClientID; //gives client side id of the Linkbutton
```

But keep in mind that grid should contain th rows, otherwise you will get `null`. If you need all `Linkbutton` instances, then you can loop through the datarows to get each linkbutton ids.

Comment: i tried this but iam getting this errror    Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: You have to bind the grid on `page_load` outside `If(!isPostback)` condition. and this should contain atleast one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
 protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      foreach(GridViewRow row in  gvdatasubcategory.Rows)
      {
          LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("button1");
          string strClientID = string.Empty;
          strClientID = btn.ClientID;
      }
 }
```

Comment: i tried this code but but breakpoint  not going to inside the loop

Comment: The gridview must have some rows to get the button inside the rows

Comment: could you plz give me example

Comment: in my gridview have some rows but iam not getting